# Cobalt chemosynthesis?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

I want to create a world where everything revolves around cobalt and I was wondering if there are autotrophs that receive energy due to chemosynthesis involving cobalt compounds, is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community - Is that you, Bot?  This is a straight up question of fact in the service of worldbuilding: cobalt containing biomolecules and energy metabolism.  Lets see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any extant examples, cobalt rich environments are pretty rare on Earth these days so that doesn't surprise me. It should be possible for a pathway from CoO (Co<sup>+2</sup>) to CoO(OH)<sub>3</sub> (Co<sup>+3</sup>) to be used in the same way that [Iron Oxidising Bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron-oxidizing_bacteria) use the Fe<sup>+2</sup>->Fe<sup>+3</sup> conversion for metabolic energy but I'm not sure of the *exact* chemistry and energy of that exchange so it may not be sufficiently efficient.